Struggling to Filter & Sort
In PowerApps, I have a Screen that displays a few SharePoint lists depending on the selection from the prior screen.
On the Gallery in question, the only formula I have in the Items box is this:
Filter(FSDPositions, LanID=selectedItem.LanID)

That way, depending on the person they selected prior, it takes that LanID and displays all their Positions over time.
I am simply needing to Sort those results based on the EndDate column (newest at the top, generally NULL).
Please help!

You can sort the filtered collection like this:
SortByColumns(Filter(FSDPositions, LanID=selectedItem.LanID), "EndDate", SortOrder.Descending)

Source: Sort and SortByColumns functions
